# nullsets and pavings of nullsets 2

Tags: measure-theory

I am considering the measure space $(\mathcal{X},\mathbb{E},\mu)$ and the paving of all $\mu$-nullsets given as:

$\mathbb{N}_{\mu}=\left\{ N \subseteq \mathcal{X} : \exists E \in \mathbb{E}\hspace{0,1cm} \text{such that} \hspace{0,1cm} N\subseteq E \hspace{0,1cm} \text{and} \hspace{0,1cm} \mu(E)=0  \right\}$

I am asked to show the following:

a) $\emptyset \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$

b) If $N_{n} \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$ for $n= \left\{1,2,3,...   \right \}$ then $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty N_{n} \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$

**My attempt:**

a)

Put $E=\emptyset$ (this is possible since $E \in \mathbb{E}$, which is a $\sigma$-algebra and therefore $\emptyset \in\mathbb{E}$).

Then we have $\emptyset \in \emptyset$ and $\mu(\emptyset)=0$. This shows that $\emptyset \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$.

b) Since $N_{n} \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$ for $n= \left\{1,2,3,...   \right \}$ then we know that $N_{n}$ for $n= \left\{1,2,3,...   \right \}$ are $\mu$-nullsets. Therefore $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} N_{n}$ is also a $\mu$-nullset. This means that A is contained in a measurable set with measure 0, i.e. $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} N_{n} \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$ by definition of $\mathbb{N}_{\mu}$.

Is the above correct?

Comment: I would greatly appreciate some feeback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(b) For each $n\ge 1$, there exists $A_n\in \mathbb{E}$ s.t. $N_n\subseteq A_n$ and $\mu(A_n)=0$. Then $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}N_n\subseteq \bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n\in \mathbb{E}$ and $\mu\!\left(\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n\right)=0$. Therefore, $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}N_n\in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$.

Comment: Appreciate the response. Could you comment on why my reasoning is flawed?

Comment: You argued that $A=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}N_n$ is a $\mu$-nullset. Why is that?

Comment: In my textbook there a lemma which states tha if $A_{1}, A_{2}, ...$ is a sequence of nullsets then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$ is also a nullset. Therefore I concluded that $A$ is a $\mu$-nullset.

Comment: That's right. However, the sets $\{N_n\}$ do not necessarily belong to $\mathbb{E}$ so that $\mu(N_n)$ may not be defined and you cannot apply that lemma to $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}N_n$. Instead, you use it to show that $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n$ (in my notation) is a $\mu$-null set.

Comment: This may sound as a trivial question but why is $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} N_{n} \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n} $ ? For some reason I do not see it.

Comment: @saleem Each $N_n\subset A_n$, and if $x\in \bigcup N_n$, then $x\in N_k$ for some $k\ge 1$.